# Conditional Format Detail Row If Record Exists In Another Table

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report in Crystal Reports using 2 database tables. The first table includes employee information (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, etc.), and the second table contains training information (TrainingID, DateOfTraining, EmployeeID).

The EmployeeID field from training contains values from employees.

What I want to do is display the list of employees. IF the employeeID is present in training (TrainingID to be passed as a variable to the report.), highlight the row (e.g. -That row will be bold.)

In other words, if a record exists in both Table A and Table B, make the record bold. Otherwise leave it plain text. I'm unsure how to conditionally format this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a left outer join from {Employee.EmployeeID} to {Training.EmployeeID} then you can simply check if {Training.EmployeeID} is null:

Find the field(s) you want to make bold → right-click and select "Format Text" → go to the "Font" tab → enter a formula for "Style" by clicking the "X-2" button to the right → enter the formula `if isnull({Train.EmployeeID}) then crRegular else crBold`

If there is no corresponding entry in the Train table for that particular employee, the font will be regular, otherwise it will be bold.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. I had set my link backwards, but once I fixed that it worked exactly as I needed. Thank you.